# Extrair somente os números de uma caixa de texto em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como faco para extrair o valor numérico de uma caixa de texto em javascript, ex:

```
valor imputado = 1a321q00
valor extraido e adicionado na variável = 132100
```

Agradeço a quem me ajudar

Comment: _"caixa de texto"_ isso é um input ou uma textarea? Podes mostrar o HMLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode filtrar o valor do campo:

```
var valor_extraido = valor_extraido.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
```

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar a expressão regular para substituir todos os caracteres que não forem números, isso é representado pelo `\D`, o `g` no final significa que a substituição é feita em todos os elementos encontrados, por padrão (sem o `g`) apenas uma substituição é feita.

```
"1a321q00".replace(/\D/g, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir o input com tipo *number*:

```
<input type="number" />
```

Detalhe é que o caracter **e** pode ser utilizado, pois significa **exponenciação**.