# javascript validar se o numero contem +/-

Tags: javascript, jquery, validação

estou com um problema, tenho uma função que faz um debito no banco de dados, porem se o Usuário alterar a quantidade colocando operadores aritméticos o valor fica negativo, dessa forma creditando créditos ao usuário ao invés de descontar.

como posso validar para não permitir a entra de +/- e validar também o valor da variável dessa mesma forma.

minha funcao que faz o débito

```
function debitashop(valor){
    getCreditosPlayer(function(output) {
        var creditosplayer  = output;
        creditosplayer = parseFloat(creditosplayer);
        valor = valor.val(valor.replace(/[^\w]/gi, ''));
        valor = parseFloat(valor);

        valor = (creditosplayer - valor);
        $.ajax({
            url:  "ajax/debita.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "creditos="+valor,
            success: function(dados){
                getCreditosPlayer(function(output) {});
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Você quer validar se o operador está no meio do input ou apenas ignora-lo?

Comment: quero que nao seja permitido inserir operador, se digitar dar replace pr ''

Comment: Insere o seguinte após a linha 3: creditosplayer = creditosplayer.replace(/[^\w]/gi, '');

Comment: no caso a variavel valor ? é ela que preciso validar

Comment: seria isso /[^0-9\.]+/g, ""

Comment: Pra aceitar só números sim

Comment: Posta a resposta e aprova pra alguém que tenha uma dúvida similar posteiormente

Comment: feito, obrigado pela ajuda ^^

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Extrair somente os números de uma caixa de texto em Javascript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146803/extrair-somente-os-n%c3%bameros-de-uma-caixa-de-texto-em-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma

**Primeiro converti o valor para string. (no caso da função)**

```
valor = String(valor);
```

**Depois retirei o que não são números**

```
valor = valor.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");
```

**No caso do input, fiz mesma coisa no evento onkeyup**

Comment: Podias usar somente `\d`, ficando `.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')`.

Comment: Se você está fazendo isso para evitar abusos, precisa fazer do lado do servidor também.

Comment: Ainda pensando nisso, terei que fazer no php também

Comment: @Sergio oque muda deixando \d, desculpe a ignorância mais não entendo bem

Comment: Colocar `0-9` ou somente `\d` é o mesmo, `\d` quer dizer "número"

Comment: é se for 50,50 dai ira passar como 5050 certo ?

Comment: @Sergio sabe me dizer como ficaria em php com preg_replace ?